# Setting variation_id for product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, I am customising checkout procedure, and I need to create order using code. I tried to use following code to create an order, but I cannot put `variation_id` into product object. Assuming that I already know `product_id` and `variation_id`.

```
$my_order = wc_create_order(array('status'=>'processing','customer_id'=>$customer_id));
$my_product=new WC_Product($product_id);
$my_product->variation_id=$variation_id;
$my_order->add_product( $my_product, 1); 
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->calculate_totals();
```

Anyone knows how to add `$variation_id` into `$my_product`?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Did you ever fins an answer to this? I'm looking to do exactly the same thing.